# Make hyperref underlining have consistent height

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, underline

I want to have consistent underlining under references when `hyperref` is used. As of now, this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
}
\makeatletter
\Hy@AtBeginDocument{
  \def\@pdfborder{0 0 1}
  \def\@pdfborderstyle{/S/U/W 1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Sec.~\ref{sec:a} lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
Sec.~\ref{sec:b} ipsum

\section{A}
\label{sec:a}

\section{B}
\label{sec:b}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output with `pdflatex`:
[image]

I prefer the version which adds more space between the text and the line. I was thinking about adding some invisible box to each reference of the size of the letter `y`, but I do not know how to achieve that.

Comment: I think the reason the first line does not have the extra space is due to the fact that there are no letters on that line that go below the baseline, but on the second line there is a `p` so it goes below. Also, those indicators are added by the pdf viewer, so may depend on which viewer one is using.