# How to modify the contents of a reference, i.e. the output of \ref

Tags: cross-referencing, ref

I would like to add some text to what outputs `\ref`. So for example, instead of Sec. 2, I would have Sec. @2@. For some reason, simply redefining `\ref`:

```
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{$@$\oldref{#1}$@$}
```

does not work with `hyperref`. I know that there is `cleveref` but I would not want to use `\cref` instead of `\ref`.

I also tried to change the naming scheme of sections:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}\vphantom{y}}
```

but it produces errors.

There is a number of questions which ask a similar thing, but the answers point to built-in mechanisms, like putting the reference into parentheses.

Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{$@$\oldref{#1}$@$}

\begin{document}
Sec.~\ref{sec:a} lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
Sec.~\ref{sec:b} ipsum

\section{A}
\label{sec:a}

\section{B}
\label{sec:b}
\end{document}
```

By the way, what i really need is a solution to [Make hyperref underlining have consistent height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573223/make-hyperref-underlining-have-consistent-height) so adding `\vphantom{y}` to the output should albo be possible.

Comment: Note that you are much more likely to get help if you provide a small sample document that others can copy and test as is. Here we'll have to make it ourself and we may make assumptions that does not apply to your document.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I added a sample document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be *really* using `cleveref` features.

However, this works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\originalref}{\ref}%
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{@\originalref{#1}@}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

Section \ref{test}

\end{document}
```

You need a recent LaTeX kernel (2020-10-01 or later). If your TeX distribution is lagging behind, add

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
```

and change `\NewCommandCopy` into `\LetLtxMacro`.